# How can I describe the monodromy of this variation of singular curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, monodromy, hyperelliptic-curves, mixed-hodge-structure

Consider the family of singular hyperelliptic curves
$$
y^2 - x(x-1)^2(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-t)
$$
over $\mathbb{A}^1_t$. Over a generic point the fiber is a genus three curve where one of the genera comes from a nodal degeneration. Over any of the singular points except for $1$ there is a degeneration to a genus 3 curve with two nodal degenerations. Around these points I can use the picard-lefschetz formula to describe the monodromy, but I am at a loss as to how to describe the monodromy around $t=1$. Are there any tools for accomplishing this?